# MariaDB crashing every few days

Tags: magento2, database, mariadb

I'm using Magento2 with MariaDB 10.3.27 on Debian 10.8 and i'm experiencing MariaDB crash every few days. I have no idea what can cause those unexpected crashes. I'm sending my config and crash logs. Maybe someone had similar issues?

```
--basedir=/usr
--bind-address=127.0.0.1
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql
--expire_logs_days=10
--key_buffer_size=16M
--log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
--max_allowed_packet=16M
--max_binlog_size=100M
--max_connections=151
--pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
--port=3306
--skip-external-locking
--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
--ssl=false
--ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
--ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
--ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
--thread_cache_size=8
--thread_stack=256K
--tmpdir=/tmp
--user=mysql
```

```
2021-04-12  6:45:45 86 [Note] Detected table cache mutex contention at instance 1: 20% waits. Additional table cache instance activated. Number of instances after activation: 2.
2021-04-12 07:20:14 0x7f86f8df4700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file /build/mariadb-10.3-Zg5BW3/mariadb-10.3-10.3.27/storage/innobase/include/ut0lst.h line 334
InnoDB: Failing assertion: list.count > 0
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
210412  7:20:14 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=66
max_threads=153
thread_count=21
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 352736 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f86e0000c08
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f86f8df3d58 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x55c1666a191e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x54d)[0x55c1661d02ed]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12730)[0x7f87236c2730]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x10b)[0x7f8722c7f7bb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x121)[0x7f8722c6a535]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4e4537)[0x55c165f14537]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4c799a)[0x55c165ef799a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xaa86cc)[0x55c1664d86cc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4e84f9)[0x55c165f184f9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa7f563)[0x55c1664af563]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa80a3d)[0x55c1664b0a3d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa810b1)[0x55c1664b10b1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa68490)[0x55c166498490]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa82760)[0x55c1664b2760]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa82a29)[0x55c1664b2a29]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa4209a)[0x55c16647209a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa48f26)[0x55c166478f26]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9d11d2)[0x55c1664011d2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9d1f16)[0x55c166401f16]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9d2f29)[0x55c166402f29]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x998f38)[0x55c1663c8f38]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa0bd00)[0x55c16643bd00]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9f7f28)[0x55c166427f28]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7fa3)[0x7f87236b7fa3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f)[0x7f8722d414cf]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x0): (null)
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on

The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

We think the query pointer is invalid, but we will try to print it anyway.
Query:

Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             3552                 3552                 processes
Max open files            16384                16384                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       3552                 3552                 signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Core pattern: core

2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-04-12  7:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=495883488607
2021-04-12  7:20:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 1064 pages from redo log.
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.27 started; log sequence number 495890286066; transaction id 30612869
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Warning] Failed to setup SSL
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Warning] SSL error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 10
2021-04-12  7:20:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210412  7:20:22
210412 10:20:13 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=26
max_threads=153
thread_count=22
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 352736 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x5561bfdef91e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x54d)[0x5561bf91e2ed]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12730)[0x7f8f42812730]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x99d4cc)[0x5561bfb1b4cc]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa362fe)[0x5561bfbb42fe]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa3c958)[0x5561bfbba958]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa48cf7)[0x5561bfbc6cf7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa4e588)[0x5561bfbcc588]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x949de0)[0x5561bfac7de0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x94fca1)[0x5561bfacdca1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa6941c)[0x5561bfbe741c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xabbaba)[0x5561bfc39aba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x9f8c90)[0x5561bfb76c90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7fa3)[0x7f8f42807fa3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f)[0x7f8f41e914cf]
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=497216384734
2021-04-12 10:20:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 1068 pages from redo log.
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.27 started; log sequence number 497234563756; transaction id 30720476
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Warning] Failed to setup SSL
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Warning] SSL error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 10
2021-04-12 10:20:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210412 10:20:20
malloc(): mismatching next->prev_size (unsorted)
210412 13:20:16 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=29
max_threads=153
thread_count=22
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 352736 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f619405d3d8
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f6278146dd8 thread_stack 0x40000
2021-04-12 13:29:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-04-12 13:29:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-04-12 13:29:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-04-12 13:29:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-04-12 13:29:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-04-12 13:29:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=498410802237
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 1001 row operations to undo
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 30808447
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 49 pages from redo log.
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of recovered transactions
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 30808427
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.27 started; log sequence number 498410809183; transaction id 30808449
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Warning] Failed to setup SSL
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Warning] SSL error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 10
2021-04-12 13:29:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210412 13:29:16
2021-04-12 14:28:44 14933 [Warning] Aborted connection 14933 to db: 'magento' user: 'magento' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2021-04-12 14:40:23 17300 [Warning] Aborted connection 17300 to db: 'magento' user: 'magento' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I've also opened ticket here https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25394. Meanwhile i'll colledt as much information as i can.

Comment: @Darius-Bilewicz Any chance you will post additional information requested May 3, 2021 next week?

Comment: @Darius-Bilewicz Resolved or still collecting information?  We know you are busy.

Comment: With thread_cache_size=8, you may be thread starved.  Try thread_cache_size=100, please.